# How to consume shared/common groovy methods in context of Jenkins Job DSL Plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

using GroovyConsole I have file main.groovy with:

```
new Helpers().test("test method called")
```

and in the same dir have file Helpers.groovy with content

```
def test(String str) {
    println "test method called with: " + str
}
```

Running results in results:

```
groovy> new Helpers().test("test method called") 

test method called with: test method called
```

However, in the context of Jenkins using DSL, I have similar code, in file generator.groovy:

```
new Helpers().test("test method called")
```

then in Helpers.groovy in same dir I have:

```
def test(String str) {
    println("test method called on: " + str)
}
```

However when I run I do not get any output (from the println) in the logs.
If I have my def's in the same main.groovy file instead, it works fine.

Probably missing something fundamental. It's compiling / green in jenkins so not sure how to adapt this, so the runtime will do what I want.

Comment: Which logs are you looking for the output in, the console output from the job or the jenkins system log? Jenkins hijacks println and sends it to the job "console output ", however System.out will still write to the server log

Comment: I was looking at the the console output, so then it should be there, but it's not. 
Feels like an issue around whether code separated out can share 'context' maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import class when call method from [other files](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples)

> Make a directory at the same level as the DSL called utilities and create a file called MyUtilities.groovy in the utilities directory with the following contents:
>
> ```
> package utilities
>
> class MyUtilities {
>     static void addMyFeature(def job) {
>         job.with {
>             description('Arbitrary feature')
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then from the DSL, add something like this:
>
> ```
> import utilities.MyUtilities
> ```

Comment: So is this code example showing that you can have shared/common Jenkins DSL code though? For example scm, configure, logRotator?